# Solving Fourth-Order ODE BVP using dsolve()

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I'm attempting to solve the following ODE using Matlab's built-in function dsolve

$$\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}=w$$
with the following boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{dx}(0)&=0\\
\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}(0)&=0\\
\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}(L)&=0\\
\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}(L)&=0    
\end{align}

I first tried to use the following code

`syms w(x)`

`a = 1;`

`L = 1;`

`Dw = diff(w,1);`

`D2w = diff(w,2);`

`D3w = diff(w,3);`

`w = dsolve(diff(w,4) - a*w == 0, Dw(0) == 0, D3w(0) == 0,D2w(L) == 0, D3w(L) == 0)`

But, this only lead to the trivial solution $u=0$, which I think was due to having the boundary condition $\frac{dw}{dx}(0)=0$. I tried to remedy this by setting the zero boundary conditions equal to $eps == 2.2204e-16$, which for all practically purposes is equal to zero.

I did get a nontrivial solution which solved the ODE, but I want to see if this is a reasonable approach to match the boundary condition.

Thanks for any feedback, and sorry for the poor Matlab code formatting!

Comment: There is no nontrivial solution when $L=1$. This would mean that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & i & -i \\ 1 & -1 & -i & i \\ e^L & e^{-L} & -e^{iL} & -e^{-iL} \\ e^L & -e^{-L} & -ie^{iL} & ie^{-iL} \end{bmatrix}$, which maps the coefficients in the general solution $c_1 e^t + c_2 e^{-t} + c_3 e^{it} + c_4 e^{-it}$ to the derivatives that you want to compute, is singular when $L=1$. But it isn't.

Comment: When I use the code I gave, the output Matlab gave was $w=0$. I'm not 100% sure what the matrix you wrote is, are the columns/rows the basis for the solution space?

Comment: Also, if I'm asking this question in the wrong place, what SE site would be more suited?

Comment: Let $w=c_1 e^t + c_2 e^{-t} + c_3 e^{-it} + c_4 e^{-it}$ (the general solution to the DE) and let $A$ be that matrix. Then $A \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ c_4 \end{bmatrix}$ is the vector of your boundary condition values. Since the boundary conditions are all zero, the only way this can have a nontrivial solution is if $A$ is singular.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. So why does Matlab give me $w=0$? I know it clearly solves the problem, but can I make Matlab find nontrivial solutions?

Comment: ...In this case no because there aren't any. Perhaps there is a value of $L$ where there is a nontrivial solution?

Comment: For my case, $L>0$, and its going to be a fixed number, but can be changed, depending on the set up. Practically speaking, it can be considered as the length of a beam. And the boundary conditions I gave above are the boundary conditions of the beam. So in total, it would not be advisable to replace 0 zero with eps in Matlab?

Comment: No, you will change the problem if you do that. There are different routines for eigenvalue problems (which is this really is) anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}=w$$
Obviously, $e^x$ , $e^{-x}$ , $e^{ix} , e^{-ix}$ are independent particular solutions. So, the general solution can be expressed with linear combinations of them, for example :
$$w=c_1\cosh(x)+c_2\sinh(x)+c_3\cos(x)+c_4\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{dw}{dx}=c_1\sinh(x)+c_2\cosh(x)-c_3\sin(x)+c_4\cos(x)$$
$$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}=c_1\cosh(x)+c_2\sinh(x)-c_3\cos(x)-c_4\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}=c_1\sinh(x)+c_2\cosh(x)+c_3\sin(x)-c_4\cos(x)$$
The conditions are :
$$\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{dw}{dx}\right)_{x=0}=c_2+c_4=0\\
\left(\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}\right)_{x=0}=c_2-c_4=0\\
\left(\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}\right)_{x=L}=c_1\cosh(L)+c_2\sinh(L)-c_3\cos(L)-c_4\sin(L)=0\\
\left(\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}\right)_{x=L}=c_1\sinh(L)+c_2\cosh(L)+c_3\sin(L)-c_4\cos(L)=0
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
c_2=0\\
c_4=0\\
\left(\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}\right)_{x=L}=c_1\cosh(L)-c_3\cos(L)=0\\
\left(\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}\right)_{x=L}=c_1\sinh(L)+c_3\sin(L)=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{c_1}{c_3}=\frac{\cos(L)}{\cosh(L)}=-\frac{\sin(L)}{\sinh(L)} \quad\to\quad \tanh(L)=-\tan(L) $$
General case (not particular value of $L$) :
$$\tanh(L)\neq\tan(L) \quad\to\quad \text{ony the trivial solution } w=0$$

Particular cases of $L=L_p$ so that $\tanh(L_p)=-\tan(L_p)$ :
$$w=c_3\left(\frac{c_1}{c_3}\cosh(x)+\cos(x)\right)=c_3\left(\frac{\cos(L_p)}{\cosh(L_p)}\cosh(x)+\cos(x)\right)$$
and with $C=\frac{c_3}{\cosh(L_p)}$
$$w(x)=C\left(\cos(L_p)\cosh(x)+\cosh(L_p)\cos(x)\right)$$